# Unable to set html element value from automatic calculation from javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a simple JavaScript function to calculate date difference in my desired format. It is written in function `clt(i)`. It is printing `LoS_days`, `Los_months` and `Los_years` value very correctly. I am using these calculated values as input of another function called function `total()`. It is written with to add these three date differences. But is not working properly. The reason is that it is not getting values from html form properly. I am attaching the complete code.

```
<html>
<head><script language="javascript" src="cal2.js">
</script>
<script language="javascript" src="cal_conf2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function total(){
    var td;
    var fd=document.getElementById("LoS_days1").value;
    var sd=document.getElementById("LoS_days2").value;
    var ld=document.getElementById("LoS_days3").value;

    var tm;
    var fm=document.getElementById("LoS_months1").value;
    var sm=document.getElementById("LoS_months2").value;
    var lm=document.getElementById("LoS_months3").value;

    var ty;
    var fy=document.getElementById("LoS_year1").value;
    var sy=document.getElementById("LoS_year2").value;
    var ly=document.getElementById("LoS_year3").value;

    td = (fd +sd +ld);
    var rd = td%30;
    var cm = Math.floor(td/30);
    document.getElementById("Totalexp_day").value=rd;

    tm = (cm + fm +sm +lm);
    var rm = tm%12;
    var cy = Math.floor(tm/12);
    document.getElementById("Totalexp_month").value=rm;


    ty = (cy + fy +sy +ly);
    document.getElementById("Totalexp_year").value=ty;


    //document.write("Difference: "+rd+" remaining days; "+cm+" carry forward months; "+td+" total days; ");
}
function clt(i){
// start year may be a leap year. if(startYears%4==0) { datesPerMonth[0]=29; }
    var datesPerMonth=new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
    var x=document.getElementById("PoS_from"+i);
    var startDate=x.value;

    var y=document.getElementById("PoS_to"+i);
    var endDate=y.value;
    //var startDate='2015/02/21';
    //var endDate='2015/03/01';

    var startExplode=startDate.split('/');
        var startYears=parseInt(startExplode[0],10);
        var startMonths=parseInt(startExplode[1],10);
        var startDays=parseInt(startExplode[2],10);
    var endExplode=endDate.split('/');
        var endYears=parseInt(endExplode[0],10);
        var endMonths=parseInt(endExplode[1],10);
        var endDays=parseInt(endExplode[2],10);

        endDays++; if(endDays>datesPerMonth[endMonths]) { endDays=1; endMonths++; if(endMonths==13) { endMonths=1; endYears++; } }

    startDate=new Date(startDate).getTime();
    endDate=new Date(endDate).getTime();

    if((startYears < endYears || startMonths < endMonths || startDays < endDays) && startDate < endDate) {


        var dateDifference=endDate-startDate;


        if(endYears%4==0) { datesPerMonth[1]=29; }
        if(endYears%100==0 && endYears%400>0) { datesPerMonth[1]=28; }

        if(startDays<=datesPerMonth[startMonths]) {
            if(endDays<=datesPerMonth[endMonths]) {

                var diffYears=endYears-startYears; // if(endMonths < startMonths || (endMonths == startMonths && endDays < startDays)) { diffYears--; }
                var diffMonths=endMonths-startMonths; if(diffMonths < 0) { diffYears--; diffMonths=(12+diffMonths); }
                var diffDays=endDays-startDays; if(diffDays < 0) { diffMonths--; if(diffMonths<0) { diffYears--; diffMonths=(12+diffMonths); } diffDays=datesPerMonth[(endMonths==1?12:(endMonths-1))]+diffDays; }

            document.getElementById("LoS_year"+i).value=diffYears;
            document.getElementById("LoS_months"+i).value=diffMonths;
            document.getElementById("LoS_days"+i).value=diffDays;
                //document.write("Difference: "+diffYears+" years; "+diffMonths+" months; "+diffDays+" days");
            }
            else { document.write('Bad end'); }
        }
        else { document.write('Bad start'); }
    }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name ="applicationform_A01" id ="applicationform_A01" method ="post" action="savemyform.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit = "return ValidateForm()">
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="76%" height="125">
  <tr>
    <td width="5%" rowspan="2" align="center" height="33"><font face="Arial" size="2">Sl. 
    No.</font></td>
    <td width="24%" rowspan="2" align="center" height="33"><font face="Arial" size="2">
    Employer Name with Address</font></td>
    <td width="22%" rowspan="2" align="center" height="33">
    <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: Arial">
    Post/Designation and Pay</span></td>
    <td width="29%" colspan="2" align="center" height="16"><font face="Arial" size="2">
    Period of Service</font></td>
    <td width="20%" colspan="3" align="center" height="16"><font face="Arial" size="2">
    Length of Service</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="14%" align="center" height="16"><font face="Arial" size="2">From</font></td>
    <td width="15%" align="center" height="16"><font face="Arial" size="2">To</font></td>
    <td width="7%" align="center" height="16"><font face="Arial" size="2">Years</font></td>
    <td width="6%" align="center" height="16"><font face="Arial" size="2">Months</font></td>
    <td width="7%" align="center" height="16"><font face="Arial" size="2">Days</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="5%" align="center" height="23"><font face="Arial" size="2">01</font></td>
    <td width="24%" height="23">
   <input type="text" name="employer1" size="30"></font>
    </td>
    <td width="22%" height="23"><font face="Arial"><input type="text" name="post1" size="30"></font></td>
    <td width="14%" height="23"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="PoS_from1" id="PoS_from1"  size="10" ><font size="1" color="#0000FF"><a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar4')">calender</a></font>
          <font face="Arial"</font></font></td>
    <td width="15%" height="23"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="PoS_to1" id="PoS_to1"  size="10" onchange="clt(1); total()" ><font size="1" color="#0000FF"><a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar5')">calender</a></font>
          <font face="Arial"</font></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="23"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="LoS_year1" id="LoS_year1"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
    <td width="6%" height="23"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="LoS_months1" id="LoS_months1"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="23"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="LoS_days1" id="LoS_days1"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="5%" align="center" height="21"><font face="Arial" size="2">02</font></td>
    <td width="24%" height="21"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="employer2" size="30"></font></td>
    <td width="22%" height="21"><font face="Arial"><input type="text" name="post2" size="30"></font></td>
    <td width="14%" height="21"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="PoS_from2" id="PoS_from2"  size="10" ><font size="1" color="#0000FF"><a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar6')">calender</a></font>
          <font face="Arial"></font></font></td>
    <td width="15%" height="21"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="PoS_to2" id="PoS_to2"  size="10" onchange="clt(2); total()"><font size="1" color="#0000FF"><a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar7')">calender</a></font>
          <font face="Arial"</font></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="21"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="LoS_year2" id="LoS_year2"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
    <td width="6%" height="21"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="LoS_months2" id="LoS_months2"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="21"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="LoS_days2" id="LoS_days2"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
  </tr>



  <tr>
    <td width="5%" align="center" height="22"><font face="Arial" size="2">03</font></td>
    <td width="24%" height="22"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="employer3" size="30"></font></td>
    <td width="22%" height="22"><font face="Arial"><input type="text" name="post3" size="30"></font></td>
    <td width="14%" height="22"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="PoS_from3" id="PoS_from3"   size="10" ><font size="1" color="#0000FF"><a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar8')">calender</a></font>
          <font face="Arial"</font></font></td>
    <td width="15%" height="22"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="PoS_to3" id="PoS_to3"  size="10" onchange="clt(3); total()"><font size="1" color="#0000FF"><a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar9')">calender</a></font>
          <font face="Arial"</font></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="22"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="LoS_year3" id="LoS_year3"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
    <td width="6%" height="22"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="LoS_months3" id="LoS_months3"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="22"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="LoS_days3" id="LoS_days3"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="80%" colspan="5" height="22">
    <p align="right"><font face="Arial" size="2">Total Experience&nbsp; </font>
    </td>
    <td width="7%" height="22"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="Totalexp_year" id="Totalexp_year"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
    <td width="6%" height="22"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="Totalexp_month" id="Totalexp_month"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="22"><font face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="Totalexp_day" id="Totalexp_day"  size="6" readonly></font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's *a lot* of code for everybody here to read.  Can you narrow it down at all?  When you step through the code in a debugger, where specifically is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

Add your script code after

end of /body

tag may be this is help full for you

Comment: I am not able to set html element value from javascript function clt(i) although it is showing correct result.

Comment: Take your form field out of table tags then try ,